# Does there exist a smooth function which may map a set of $0$ measure to a set of positive measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Does there exist a smooth function which may map a set of $0$ measure to a set of positive measure?

The devil's starircase+ $x$ is a function which maps the Cantor set to a set of positive measure, but it is not smooth (not even differentiable)

I am trying to prove Sard's Theorem, and the non-existence of such a function might make life easy for me in some special cases.

EDIT: Consider only the Lebesgue measure on both the domain and the range, which for now consider to be $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: If you take Lebesgue measure on the domain and counting measure on the co-domain ... or for example a projection $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen- I am only considering examples in which the measure on both the domain and range is the Lebesgue measure. Maybe I should make that explicit in the question

Comment: Well, $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto x$ with $E=\Bbb R\times\{0\}$  works with Lebesgue measure in both places ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen- I see. I was also mainly imagining functions from $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. Sorry it would seem I keep imposing extraneous conditions.

Comment: HagenvonEitzen has provided an excellent answer. Just let me add, as a curiosity, that there exists a function that maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]^2$ which is differentiable almost everywhere!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $f\colon [0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable and $E\subset [0,1]$ is a zero set whereas $\mu(f(E))=1$. 
Then for any $\epsilon>0$,  $E$ can be covered by intervals $A_i$ of total length $\epsilon$. Each $A_i$ is mapped to some interval $B_i$, and from $\sum|B_i|\ge1$, we see that $\frac{|B_i|}{|A_i|}>\frac1\epsilon$. By the MVT, $|f'(x)|>\frac1\epsilon$ for some $x\in A_i$. Thus $f'$ is not bounded on $[0,1]$ and cannot be continuous.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot